# Python: read million of files and create one

Tags: python, file, file-io

Ok, i start with: This is not a process to do often, I do not care that some time later (but i need it finish and not take days), and must be in Python.

I need read 2 million of html files (4kb) and examine it, only one time and i create a faster program in python (I learn python today :/)

```
path = './files/*.htm'   
files = glob.glob(path)   
writer = open('myfile.txt','a+')
for name in files: 
    try:
        with open(name) as f: 
            for line in f.readlines():
                result = my_logic()

            writer.write(result) #Concatenated string

writer.close()
```

And well, I think when I go to run this with millions of htm, all explode and my entire office will die. Sooo...Any small suggestion?
I totally noob in Python but i think i most harder create this with javascript :P

EDIT:

i explained my questions sorry :P

Is this the best way to open the files?
I do not understand much Python and understand that 'files' var can have a giant size (do not know if saved values or reference only) with millions of files to read.

Open the Writer and leave it open throughout the program? He save every time he write or lose all if the program fail?

Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: No, it won't explode, you are processing a file at time, a row at time, I don't see how this could be heavy on the system. What's the question again?

Comment: Other than `result` not being defined anywhere, looks fine to me. Run it and see if it works - it probably won't explode.

Comment: If you know your code works and you just want to generally improve it, try asking on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I explained more my questions, sorry for the inconvenience and thanks for anwers :D

Comment: You should split up your work in more processes to exploit multi-core architecture. The exact solution obviously depends in what you have available, but this operation is completely data parallelizable as far as I can see.

Comment: You've got a `try:`, where's the `except`?

Comment: I change all my code for my_logic() and forgot put the except IOError, for resume code in the question ^^U

Answer (score 1):

You are creating `2000000` unnecessary lists using readlines, you also need to `join` the name to the path, you have 8 gigs of data so unless you are doing some serious amounts of work in `my_logic()` it won't be taking days.

```
path = './files/'
files = glob.glob(path)
with open('myfile.txt', 'a+') as writer:
    for name in glob.glob(path + "*.html"):
        try:
            with open(os.path.join(path, name)) as f: # join path and filename
                for line in f: # iterate over file object
                    result = my_logic()
                writer.write(result)  #Concatenated string
        except IOError as e:
            print(e)
```